# Add column above when row is moved and the row above changes

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple formula that takes the value from the Cell above and adds it to a referenced cell so that each cell will accumulate values above it. However, if I move the row from its position (e.g. move Row 25 to Row 2 spot the formula still reference the previous cell from Row 24. I want to have the add function always reference the cell above.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZnDicI8u40sijSQEuk9HSs7KCqmr1oaYcdmyLgPIABk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178679/get-value-from-the-cell-above

Comment: possible. sheet is private - share it