# How do I refer to the cell a formula is written in in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to write a formula to add the contents of a column in cell D5, so normally I would write **=SUM(D2:D4)**. However, the location of the formula cell (currently D5) will change as I add more rows. How do I write a formula that accounts for this?

(The formula I want would hypothetically look something like **=SUM(D2:CellAboveCurrentCell)**.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

**=Sum(D2:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN())))**

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178679/get-value-from-the-cell-above) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INDEX` function:

```
=SUM(D2:INDEX(D:D;ROW()-1;1))
```

[image]